# Telerik grid disable onrowselected event once a row is selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I am using `Html.Telerik().Grid` in my asp.net MVC 3 project where in i have a Grid (Telerik grid) which sows searchResults, User has facility to click on these rows to see more information of the particular row in a new page which is opened in the new window. I am also using Jquery to handle the `onrowselected` event and i am doing a post to the controller to fetch the details.

**Jquery code:**

```
 function onRowSelected(e) {
        var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
       //populate criteria here

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: //"some url",
            data: //data to controller,
            dataType: "text json",
            success:
        function (data, textStatus) {
            if (data != "Success") {
                ShowError(data);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = //"redirect";
            }
        }
        }

        });
```

I dont want the user to select anything else on the page and want him to just wait until the details are loaded i.e. once he selects a row he should not be able to select any other row in the grid. Any way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using a loading progress pop-up that will prevent the user from selecting anything else and indicate that some action is happening behind the scenes.

Here is a plugin that I've used before http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-showLoading

Implementation would be fairly simple, after including the the plug-in script:

```
function onRowSelected(e) {
    $('#someID').showLoading();  //To show the loading progress bar, someID could be the div that contains the grid.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: //"some url",
        data: //data to controller,
        dataType: "text json",
        success:
            function (data, textStatus) {
                 $('#someID').hideLoading();  //To hide the loading progress bar
            }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

Alternatively you could try something like this, it will show the overlay hiding the whole page and a loading picture in the middle of the screen.

Add the following styling to your page, you'll have to find an image and edit the path in the background attribute of the .loading-indicator class:

```
<style type="text/css">
.loading-indicator {
    position: absolute; 
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1001;
    background: url( '../images/loading.gif' );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.loading-indicator-overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
</style>
```

Add javascript to show and hide the loading bar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showLoadingBar() {
    $('#overlay').addClass('loading-indicator-overlay');
    $('#loadingbar').addClass('loading-indicator');
}

function hideLoadingBar() {
    $('#overlay').removeClass('loading-indicator-overlay');
    $('#loadingbar').removeClass('loading-indicator');
}
</script>
```

Add the following div tags to the page:

```
<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="loadingbar"></div>
    ....
    ....
</body>
```

Now you can call the showLoadingBar() or hideLoadingBar() to block the user from interacting with the page, while you do some background processing. You'll have to test that css to make sure it is compatible with the main stream browsers.

Comment: any way of doing it without using a plugin ... i mean by just using a loading gif image and some css can we achieve this?

Comment: Yes you could, but that is exactly what this plugin is. Just a bit of css and some light weight javascript, plus it has been tested on main stream browsers. I'll edit the main answer with some more code.

Comment: The plugin works fine... but i tried the above css+jquery which is not working as expected :( it only shows the loading gif and a small black strip behind it but doesnt grey out the whole page

Comment: Works fine for me, tried in IE, Chrome and Firefox. Where did you place the overlay and loadingbar divs?

Comment: i placed it on the top of my telerik Grid code. which is in a partial view

Comment: Try placing them directly inside the body tag. If you want it to just block out the grid, you'll have to set the height and width of the overlay css at runtime with js to match the dimensions of the grid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11988/discussion-between-rutwik-reddy-and-igorrious)

Comment: opacity alone doesn't work for IE.. instead use filter:alpha(opacity=50);